# gyp ERR! stack at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:154:17)

Tags: node.js

I am working on the nodeJS project, i am running "npm install" command, but getting below, i tried multiple stackoverflow solutions, but nothing worked for me, please help with the below.

Error output:
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: incorrect header check
gyp ERR! stack     at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:154:17)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763

i tried multiple stackoverflow solutions, but nothing worked, please help with that.